# Lexical Environment и Record Environment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Хотелось бы увидеть четкое определение Lexical Environment и Record Environment (с пояснениями) и псевдокод, который бы пояснил происходящее.

Comment: определение [Lexical Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-lexical-environments), определение [Environment Record](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-environment-records)